# ag-grid : show dropdown on cell of grid with angular

Tags: angular, angular8, ag-grid

I am working with angular 8 andI am able to render the ag-grid, but I also need to show the dropdown on cell, so i added the code like below :

that's a ts file code with single column.

```
this.columns[0] = {
  headerName: 'a', field: 'a', cellEditorParams: {
    cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
    values: ['a','b','c'],

  },
};
this.defaultColDef = {
  flex: 1,
  minWidth: 80,
  editable: true,
  resizable: true,
};
```

for html file, I have code as below :

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
            [rowData]="rows" [columnDefs]="columns" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef">
```

here the rows is empty, I want to show the dropdown with a,b,c as value whether the column is empty or filled with some value.

do we need to buy the enterprise edition of ag-grid to use agRichSelectCellEditor

following this [tutorial](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/)

Answer (score 3):

**agRichSelectCellEditor** is Available in ag-Grid Enterprise only.
An alternative to using the browser's **select** popup for dropdowns inside the grid.

You can create your own custom editor for showing dropdown in the cell.
Follow the link - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/

Comment: Actually I created the grid as define above, now when we use the customized one we have to create a object as gridOptions, so how can i pass that.

Comment: No, you just have to pass your custom editor in cellEditor. Refer the example of custom editor - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-celleditor-kkfh8y

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also use AGGrid's default `cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor'` inside your column config.

Ref: https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/provided-cell-editors/#select-cell-editor

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement. And I have made use of `cellEditor: agSelectCellEditor` with a minor tweak to meet our expectations.

```js
const columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  {
    headerName: 'Action',
    field: 'action',
    minWidth: 150,
    pinned: 'right',
    filter: false,
    headerClass: 'action_header',
    editable: this.showAllowableSelectEditor.bind(this),
    cellRenderer: this.getSelectedValue.bind(this),
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
      values:['Select Stage', 'Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5'],
      handleGridCellEvent: this.onDataChangeHandler.bind(this),
    },
  },
] as ColDef[];
```

Explanation on some of the callbacks function that I have to use to meet my requirement:

1. **cellRenderer: this.getSelectedValue.bind(this)** - By default, it returns the default value that needed to be shown in the `agGrid` cell. And If any value is selected then it returns that value.

**Note:** I had to return the default value as `Select Stage` (in this case) so that the default value can be displayed on grid load and that tells the user that there should be a value selected if needed.

For e.g.

```js
private getSelectedValue(params: ICellRendererParams): string {
    return params.value ? 
      params.value :
      (['Failed', 'Completed'].includes(params.data.status)) && !params.value ? 'Selecte Stage' : '');
  }
```

2. **this.showAllowableSelectEditor.bind(this)** - Used to show/hide the dropdowns conditionally. In my case, the dropdown needed to be displayed only when the status is **Failed** or **Completed**.

For e.g.

```js
private showAllowableSelectEditor(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    return ['Failed', 'Completed'].includes(params.data.status);
  }
```

3. **this.onDataChangeHandler.bind(this)** - Finally, on data selection from the dropdown, I had to make an API call.

With the above-mentioned implementation, everything worked as per our expectations!

Screenshot are attached for reference.
[image]
[image]

I hope the above-shared info helps.