# How to enable dropdown when I click the table cell

Tags: html, angular, grid, dropdown

I have a grid with 4 columns. In one of the column (say column 2) I have added this ng-template code. So that each cells in column 2 will have this ng template functionality. (used synfusion grid where we have e-columns)

```
                <ng-template #template let-data>
                    <div *ngIf="!enabledDropDownClicked">
                      {{data.status}}                    //  displays the status value in column 2 cells
                    </div>
                    <div id="codeSetDropdown" *ngIf="enabledDropDownClicked">
                      <select [(ngModel)]="data.status">
                        <option *ngFor="let val of dropdown_array" [value]="val.status">
                          {{val.status}}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </ng-template>
```

My requirement is this:
My application has a grid of 4 columns with hidden dropdown feature for column 2.
My application has a enableDropDown button. When I click that button, I have enabled the dropdown feature, but dropdown should not get displayed. Only why I click that particular cell, the corresponding cell dropdown should appear.

Currently, when i click on enableDropDown button, all cells in that particular column are displaying the dropdown. (But I need dropdown displayed only for the particular cell that is clicked.)

Kindly help me

Comment: have a look to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791373/ag-grid-show-dropdown-on-cell-of-grid-with-angular and https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-celleditor-kkfh8y?file=app%2Fmy-grid-application%2Fmy-grid-application.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, but his is ag-grid. However, I am using synfusion grid. So the solution you provided is not compatible.